# .stretched-link broken with parent CSS transform: translate

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

With Boostrap 5, if a .stretched-link is on an element which have a CSS transform translate, the stretched-link doesn't work.

How can I deal with that ?

```css
.btn {
  transform: translate(0,0);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="p-4">
  <div class="p-4 bg-warning position-relative">
    <a href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/helpers/stretched-link/" class="btn btn-primary stretched-link">Button</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The translation changes the position properties of the button, which then contains the pseudo-element which `.stretched-link` applies *to* the button. It's as though `position: relative` had been given to the button, which makes *it* the containing element of the pseudo-element instead of the div.

You can overcome this by wrapping the button in an element and applying translation to it instead.

```css
.translated {
  transform: translate(0);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="p-4">
  <div class="p-4 bg-warning position-relative">
    <span class="translated"><a href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/helpers/stretched-link/" class="btn btn-primary stretched-link">Button</a></span>
  </div>
</div>
```